# Sass Syntax Error in assets:precompile with a .css file in vendor folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I use rails `4.1.7` and include one custome css template in `application.css.scss` and put the custome css file(ace.css) in `vender/assets/stylesheets` folder.

application.css.scss:

```
/*
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require ace-fonts
 *= require ace  <----
 *= require_self
 *= require attr_filter
 */
```

I run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` it shows error:

```
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...th: 991px) and ": expected media expression (e.g. (min-device-width: 800px)), was "only screen and..."
  (in /Users/xushanchuan/projects/newmerger/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)
(sass):11576
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

But when I remove the `ace.css` file, assets:precompile works. Why a css file make `Sass::SyntaxError`?

Comment: attach you ace.css file or check it, it could be possible that ace.css has some syntax error at any line.

Comment: Is the ace file supposed to be processed with SASS?  Maybe (as suggested above) it's not valid css, but instead is valid SCSS or SASS.  You could try adding a .scss extension to it and see if it gets preprocessed properly.

Comment: I checked it, the error message said "only screen and..." is wrong. I dont know why. It is css not scss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, the only way to solve this problem is to remove the so called error syntax: 'only screen and'.